# SFDX force:auth:web:login not working in Visual Studio Code

Tags: salesforcedx, visualstudiocode

I am able to open via bash and powershell, but when I use Visual Studio Code's built in terminal it does not work.  Anyone else having this problem?

Comment: Can you be more specific on "does not work"? What is the error you get (if any)? Does it work, but disappear when closing the terminal? Are your environment parameters visible in VSC terminal?

Comment: It just doesn't open a browser window for logging in, no error visual coder terminal just sits there and runs the command.  It's now been 50 minutes.

Comment: Do you see any error message in the console? You can view the console in VS Code from Help --> Toggle Developer Tools.

Comment: I can't repo this behavior on MacOS, with the newest version of both sfdx & vscode. The command takes a bit, but opens in browser.

Comment: No error message, windows 10, using latest version of vcode and sfdx

Comment: When you say "works in bash" I assume you mean WSL? Is VSCode's terminal using bash or powershell?

Comment: I am using bash

Comment: I have the same problem. I think that it might be related to Java runtime could not be located, could that be true?

Comment: @Derek F - What did you end up having to do for it to work?

Comment: @trebleCode I'm not the person who asked the question. I simply edited it. You should try looking for similar questions, and then create a question of your own if you don't find anything.

Comment: @trebleCode --- I ended up uninstalling everything from visual studio code, then uninstalled visual studio code, rebooted, reinstalled, and readded the plugins and everything worked.   Some kind of conflict.   I wish you the best of luck

Answer (score 3):

I'm also facing the same problem. Finally, I got the answer. VS Code tries to open the browser. If the application don't know the default browser, then this error will occur.
Set Google Chrome or Internet Explorer as your default browser.

Or After entering the command, wait for minute. It will ask you, the application type. Select the browser you want to authorize.